# Controls inside WebSplitter not available in Page_PreInit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, infragistics

We are facing an issue where the event of the dropwdown which is added dynamically to Grid Filter does not fire. Since the controls inside WebSplitter are not available in Page_PreInit event, the handlers added after the Page_PreInit event doesnot get fired.

1)  The HTML markup looks as below. **Note that the Grid is outside the WebSplitter**

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <ig:WebSplitter ID="WSP" runat="server">
            <Panes>
                <ig:SplitterPane runat="server">
                    <Template>

                    </Template>
                </ig:SplitterPane>
                <ig:SplitterPane runat="server"></ig:SplitterPane>
            </Panes>
        </ig:WebSplitter>

        <ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid ID="WHG" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="400px">
            <EditorProviders>
            </EditorProviders>
            <Behaviors>
                <ig:Filtering Enabled="true" CaseSensitive="false" EnableInheritance="true">
                </ig:Filtering>
            </Behaviors>
        </ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid>
```

2)  And the code as below. **Note that the AddEditor() method which adds the EditiorDropDown is called inside Page_PreInit event.**

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    'AddEditor()
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_PreInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    AddEditor()
End Sub

Protected Sub AddEditor()
    Dim sDropdownID As String = ""
    sDropdownID = "WHG_DropDownProvider"
    WHG.GridView.EditorProviders.Add(GetDropdownProvider(sDropdownID, "ID", "NAME"))
End Sub

Private Function GetDropdownProvider(ByVal i_sDropdownID As String, ByVal i_sValueField As String, ByVal i_sTextField As String) As DropDownProvider
    Dim oDropDownProv As New DropDownProvider
    oDropDownProv.ID = i_sDropdownID

    With oDropDownProv.EditorControl
        .EnableMultipleSelection = True
        .MultipleSelectionType = DropDownMultipleSelectionType.Checkbox
        .EnableAutoFiltering = AutoFiltering.Off
        .EnableAutoCompleteFirstMatch = False
        .EnableAutoCompleteFirstMatch = False
        .EnableClosingDropDownOnSelect = False
        .DataKeyFields = i_sValueField
        .ValueField = i_sValueField
        .TextField = i_sTextField
        .DropDownContainerMaxHeight = New Unit("100px")
        .DropDownContainerHeight = New Unit("100px")
        .BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
        .Width = New Unit("99%")
        AddHandler .ItemsRequested, AddressOf WHD_DropDownProvider_OnItemsRequested
        .EnableAnimations = True
        With .ClientEvents
            .DropDownOpening = "WHG_DropDownProvider_DropDownOpening"
            .DropDownClosing = "WHG_DropDownProvider_DropDownClosing"
        End With

    End With

    Return oDropDownProv
End Function
```

3)  Run the website, and try to apply filter for Field1 column, then the event which is added at runtime (WHD_DropDownProvider_OnItemsRequested) for the dropdown gets executed. (click on Filter icon and select Equals and then click on the dropdown icon)

This is how we want the filters to work in the below scenario as well.

4)  Now move the grid in HTML inside the WebSplitter. So the HTML markup looks as below.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <ig:WebSplitter ID="WSP" runat="server">
            <Panes>
                <ig:SplitterPane runat="server">
                    <Template>
                        <ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid ID="WHG" runat="server" Height="350px" Width="400px">
                            <EditorProviders>
                            </EditorProviders>
                            <Behaviors>
                                <ig:Filtering Enabled="true" CaseSensitive="false" EnableInheritance="true">
                                </ig:Filtering>
                            </Behaviors>
                        </ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid>
                    </Template>
                </ig:SplitterPane>
                <ig:SplitterPane runat="server"></ig:SplitterPane>
            </Panes>
        </ig:WebSplitter>
```

5)  Try to run the website. You will be getting Object reference error. This is because the grid is not available at Page_PreInit event.
In this case, the grid is available in Page_Init event. So call the AddEditor() method in Page_Init event.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    AddEditor()
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_PreInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    'AddEditor()
End Sub

Protected Sub AddEditor()
    Dim sDropdownID As String = ""
    sDropdownID = "WHG_DropDownProvider"
    WHG.GridView.EditorProviders.Add(GetDropdownProvider(sDropdownID, "ID", "NAME"))
End Sub
```

6)  Now try to apply filter for Field1 column. You will notice that the dropdown event does not get executed and the page just refreshes.

If the controls inside the WebSplitter is available in page_PreInit event then the problem will be solved.

### Updated (06-Nov-2014)

We found a partial solution for this. If we call AddEditor() in Page_PreLoad event then it works. But again if we do Paging/Sorting operations and then try to apply the EditorDropDown filter then it fails and throws an Object Reference error.

Comment: Try splitting `GetDropdownProvider` in 2 parts. First part will just create the dynamic control and second part will add the Event Handler. Call first part in Page_Init and the second part in Page_Load.